# Given matrix $Q$ and vector $s$, find a vector $w$ that minimizes $\| Qw-s \|^2$

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization, least-squares, quadratic-programming

The very simple, very formal description of the problem is this:

I have a real matrix $\mathrm{\textbf{Q}}$ and a real vector $\mathrm{\textbf{s}}$.

How could I calculate the vector $\mathrm{\textbf{w}}$, that I minimize $(\mathrm{\textbf{Q}}\mathrm{\textbf{w}}-\mathrm{\textbf{s}})^2$ for that?

$\mathrm{\textbf{Q}}$ is not surely square, thus $\mathrm{\textbf{w}}$ and $\mathrm{\textbf{s}}$ can have different dimensions. Singular cases are not a problem.

---

After some thinking I suspect these:

- I am essentially looking for the minimum of an n-dimensional quadratic potential. Thus, finding $\mathrm{\textbf{w}}$ if $\frac{d(\mathrm{\textbf{Q}}\mathrm{\textbf{w}}-\mathrm{\textbf{s}})^2}{\mathrm{d \textbf{w}}}=0$ will be likely a solution.
- The problem is likely to find the nearest points of two 1d lines in an n-dimensional space.

If it is true, then the solution is probably a simple formula, containing maybe a $\mathrm{\textbf{Q}}^{-1}$ and some elemental scalar vector operation. But as I tried to solve the problem, all my formulas became quickly chaotically unsolvable.

Comment: How is the square of a vector defined?

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo With scalar multiplication, i.e. the sum of the square of the components.

Comment: Google "normal equations".

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo I think the problem is easily solvable for anybody played significantly more with tensor calculus as me. Yes, this is a matching optimization problem. More exactly, I am working on a SEDE query which estimates the effect of the tags to the question scores. :-) The [first google hit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_least_squares_(mathematics)) has a partially different topic, as I can see it is mainly about matching a set of points in a 2d space with a line. I am trying to match a vector in an n-dimensional space transformed by the matrix Q.

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo But I am learning it in the moment, if no answer is coming, a self-answer is quite possible.

Comment: This problem is really easy. Differentiation produces the so-called normal equations $$Q^\top (Q w - s) = 0$$ which can be rewritten as follows $$Q^\top Q w = Q^\top s$$ which is a linear system. You may want to consult the matrix cookbook.

Comment: This is a standard problem called Least Squares Regression. Boils down to solving a linear system, as has been pointed out above.

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo Thank you very much! I think in this case, the final result will be $w={(Q^T Q)}^{-1}Q^Ts$. But I will check also the reason. :-)

Comment: @peterh Only if $Q$ has full column rank (to ensure that $Q^\top Q$ is invertible).

Comment: I would look at this problem using linear transformations. What you want is to project s on the range of Q and this is characterized by teh system of equations $<s-Qw,Qe_i>=0$ for all i.